# WhatsApp overrides do not disturb

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Android 7. A contact accidentally initiated a video call at 04.58 and my phone briefly let out a notification ( brief as I'd guess she presumably killed the call pronto?). I've just double checked and Do not disturb is set to prevent all apps' notifications at night, including WhatsApp.
Any ideas as to what happened? How I can prevent this again?

Comment: Are calls permitted as an exception?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a setting for that, at least not one that I can find. The caller is not on my exceptions list and notifications/WhatsApp doesn't go any more detailed than "override do not disturb", which is set to off.

Comment: i guess your device was on deep sleep until call woke it up, then device started to realize it's night time now and instructed WhatsApp to shut up immediately, but it was already too late ;)

Comment: I wondered if that was feasible: That seems to be a reasonable assumption.  Somewhat defeats the DND, but I suppose at least it did kick in. After we were woken up..m

Comment: exclude the clock from battery optimizing maybe it helps